# SQL: How to delete part of the string if it equals to the specific value?

Tags: sql, snowflake-schema, datagrip

I have 20 distinct strings. Eg:

```
Row 1: cat, dog, rabbit
Row 2: dog, cat
Row 3: cat
```

How do I delete only one part of the strings ('cat') and show what is left:

```
Row 1: dog, rabbit
Row 2: dog
Row 3: null
```

replace function did not work for me: in the scenario of 'dog, cat' the 'cat' remains.

Comment: Storing data as comma separated values will cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Result will depends to which DB engine you use?

Comment: I am using snowflake

Comment: you can use REGEX_REPLACE

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace)

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_REPLACE(pet_names_column, '(^|\s)cat(\s|$)', ' ') = '' 
    THEN NULL 
    ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(pet_names_column, '(^|\s)cat(\s|$)', ' ')
  END AS excluding_cats 
FROM pets_table;
```